# Problemas al crear un proyecto en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, php7

Cuando intento crear un proyecto en Laravel, con PHP 7.0 tengo los siguientes errores:

> ```
> ricky@pc:/var/www/html/proyectos$ laravel new 001
> Crafting application...
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
> - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 -> 
>
> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[4.0.8].
>     - phpunit/php-code-coverage 4.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   Problem 2
>     - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.7.19 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.19].
>     - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.19 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>
>   To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
>     - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
>   You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
> Application ready! Build something amazing.
> ```

El tema es que a pesar que me crea la estructura, cuando intento ver la versión de Artisan, obtengo lo siguiente:

> ```
> ricky@pc:/var/www/html/proyectos/001$ php artisan -V
> PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/proyectos/001/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /var/www/html/proyectos/001/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
> PHP Stack trace:
> PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/proyectos/001/artisan:0
> PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/proyectos/001/artisan:16
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/proyectos/001/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
> /var/www/html/proyectos/001/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
> PHP Stack trace:
> PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/proyectos/001/artisan:0
> PHP   2. require() /var/www/html/proyectos/001/artisan:16
> ```

Necesito saber qué debo hacer. Alguna idea?

Comment: El tema no es Laravel, es tu entorno que debes resolver lo que falta instalandolo. Si la creación desde laravel no finaliza sin errores, no va a funcionar correctamente. Empieza por ver todos los paquetes que te reporta este ir instalando uno a uno ante cada error, por ejemplo ext-dom, phpunit, etc. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias Enrique, un abrazo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto solucionó mi problema:

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom php7.0-mbstring